# 2012 Dodge Caravan! Oil mixed in cooling system due to oil cooler failure! Replaced it! Now it smokes bad! Will Bars leak work with oil in the coolan

Tags: oil, leak, head-gasket, radiator-overflow, oil-cooler

I had an oil cooler go out on my 2012 Dodge Grand caravan with a 3.6 V6 in it! It lost coolant immediately and the engine ran hot. Plus it mixed oil into the coolant system! I have purged the system the best I can! It smokes really bad now from over hearing. It blew a head gasket also! Will Bars leak work if there is any amount of oil left in the coolant system? Or will the oil prevent it from doing it's job to seal the head gasket leak?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Bars Leak is a stop gap at best with or without oil in the cooling system. If you want to run your vehicle, you'll need to get if fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I just need to use the vehicle temporarily until I can afford the head job! So the oil won't stop the Bars leak from working?I've flushed it with prestone system cleaner too! Just worried about anything left over affecting the bars leak!

Comment: TBH with you, I'd hate to tell you it's going to be good, because I'm going to bet no matter what you do it's not going to cure your issues. I'm not a big fan of Bars Leak in the first place, but in this case I'm thinking it's not going to be able to solve your issues. It might help some, but I'm thinking it's a lost cause ... sorry, not trying to be mean, but rather truthful. This is just my opinion, so leaving this as a comment instead of an answer.